# LeetCode07(Reverse Integer): Why this code works out right ouput in Dev C++ but fails in LeetCode?

Tags: c, algorithm

As a newcomer to learning to program, I meet a very confusing problem solving [LeetCode 7. Reverse Integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int reverse(int x);
int main()
{
    int a;
    while(scanf("%d",&a)!=NULL)
    {
        reverse(a);
    }
    return 0;
}
int reverse(int x){
    if(x==0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
        return 0;
    }else
    {
        int a[10];
        int i,rev,ten;
        for(i=-1;abs(x)>0;x/=10)
        {
            a[++i]=x%10;
        }
        for(ten=1,rev=0;i>=0;ten*=10,i--)
        {
            rev+=a[i]*ten;
        }
        if(rev>0)
        {
            if(rev>pow(2,31)-1)
            {
                return 0;
            }else
            {
                printf("%d\n",rev);
            }
        }else if(rev<0)
        {
            if(rev<-pow(2,31))
            {
                return 0;
            }else
            {
                printf("%d\n",rev);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In Dev C++, input test examples like 123, 120. Output: 321, 21. Obviously, it's right. But in LeetCode, input example 321, output is 0. I really don't know why would be that.
How could I get the code I submit accepted without changing the train of thought mentioned above? I need help.

Comment: (You are "invoking undefined behaviour" in using the value of `rev` without prior initialisation.)

Comment: Sorry,I don't know what is your meaning.@灰胡子

Comment: [Behaviour of C programs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a better way to do it:

First, note that in order to get the first digit on the right of `n` we can simply do `n%10`, now if we divide by 10 and repeat the same process we then can get all of the digits of a number `n`. We can write a simple algorithm:

```c
int reverse(int n)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        ret = ret*10 + n%10;
        n = n / 10l
    }
}
```

This is all good but this may result in an overflow, in a 32-bit signed integer we can store the values of [-2^(31), 2^(31)-1]=[-2,147,483,648 ,  2,147,483,647]

If we have the number `n=2,147,483,647` to reverse it, it will cause an overflow thus we can easily check this as follows:

```c
if(ret > INT_MAX / 10 || (ret == INT_MAX / 10 && ret % 10 > 7) || ret < INT_MIN / 10 || (ret == INT_MIN / 10 && ret % 10 < -8)) return 0;
```

Thus our code should look something like this:

```c
int reverse(int n) {
    int ret = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n /= 10;
        if (ret > INT_MAX / 10 || (ret == INT_MAX / 10 && n % 10 > 7)
        ||  ret < INT_MIN / 10 || (ret == INT_MIN / 10 && n % 10 < -8)) return 0;

        ret = ret * 10 + n % 10;
        }
    return ret;
}
```

I think

```
int reverse(int x){
    long long ret = 0;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        ret = ret * 10 + x % 10;
        x /= 10;
        if (ret > INT_MAX || ret < INT_MIN )         
        {
            return 0;
        }       
    }
    return ret;
}
```

will be better

Comment: Perfect!That algorithm helps me a lot!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the answer instead of printing that.

To do that, replace `printf("%d\n",rev);` with `return rev;`.

Comment: You are right.I get AC.Thank you!Have a nice day!